Snipping Tool: On delayed screenshot, how to draw selection first, then delay, then have the screenshot taken?
On Windows 11, I use the Snipping Tool to take screenshots.
I want to take screenshot of an area of a browser page showcasing a hover effect.
For that, my expectation of what I could do was:

clock menu, add 3 , 5, or 10 second delay
click + New
draw my area
prepare my browser screen with the hover effect
the screenshot is taken after the chosen delay capturing the hover effect


Yet what happens instead:

I chose a delay, e.g. 10 seconds
I click + New
Snipping Tool now waits 10 seconds to even offer me the ability to draw my selection
on drawing my selection, the screenshot is taken immediately once I finished drawing my selection

Hence, I currently cannot screenshot anything having hover effects.
Is there a setting I am missing?

Your expectation differs from how Microsoft describes the expected behaviour. According to Use Snipping Tool to capture screenshots:
First, identify the menu or other components you want to capture. 
In Snipping Tool, select Delay and then select, for example, 5 seconds. 
Select Mode to start the 5-second countdown. Within 5 seconds, open a 
menu or otherwise compose your image. At 5 seconds, when you see the screen turn gray, 
use the mouse to draw around the area you want. 

What you get after clicking on the delay is the expected behaviour. You are not missing a setting.

I just double-checked on a different Windows 11 machine: Here I can prepare my screenshot, the gray screen happens after the delay, I can draw my selection, and it takes the proper screenshot with the hover effects on place. So there is something off with my other PC. Don't have a clue yet as to why, yet this is how it should work.

These type of applications are usually coded to do a screenshot, then draw a region on said screenshots to crop it. Hence there's the behavior you described. I don't recall any application that has an option to do it the other way round.
To present a hover, I'd recommend to record a GIF anyways - much clearer showcase. Better tools than standard Windows app have this capability, e.g. ShareX can region capture an animation. You can open Hotkey settings within it and bind Start/Stop screen recording (GIF) task to a chosen key combination. Then you just remember where the hover shows and draw the area around it after pressing the shortcut.
Example:


In regards to UI, I find ShareX overloaded. I took a look around, I much prefer a tool like flameshot, and it also has the ability to add a screenshot via delay, albeit a bit cumbersome through Open Launcher > Delay > Take a new screenshot.

This is definitely a current bug in Windows 11 on Dec. 8, 2024. The “solution” mentionned above does not address the problem or the question was not understood.
It is no longer possible to take screenshots of pop-up menus with the SnippingTool and the time delay option. After time timer is completed, Snipping Tool is stealing your focus and closes the Menues before you can take the required screen shot.
An emergency solution is to start a video recording instead and then take a screen shot of the video recording.

OP here, the other answer explains the expected workflow, and the bug only appears on one of my machines. I switched to Flameshot for screenshots.
